# Which extension adds jquery?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I cannot figure out which extension adds these lines of jquery / jqueryui.

It conflicts with other extensions.

Here is a list of all installed extensions: http://pastebin.com/CX0DEi2u

I have disabled jQuery from responsive_template

Using Typo3 6.2.17

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about greping for jquery or googleapis in yout typo3conf/ext folder?

If that is not possible, you can go to the template module in your backend, choose template analyzer, scroll down and click "View the complete TS listing". Now you should find the TS that adds this and the extension it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel is right, but a quick look on your list recveal the candidates

- t3jquery => mind the name ;-)
- imagecycle